# C bit twiddling so that int 0 becomes 1, while any non-zero becomes -1? (ideally x86 intrinsic)

Tags: c, x86, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm looking for a way to achieve what I wrote in the title.
I'm doing it now with an "if" and I want to get rid of branching.
I've had a look at a couple of pages such as [this one](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html), can't find the exact thing I'm looking for.

Comment: A bit can be equal either to 1 or to 0.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please add some more details.

Comment: Your title says C++, but the tags say C. Pick one and fix the other.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, done, thank you for letting me know about it.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow those are integers, not bits. (Should be pretty clear, as "bit twiddling" on single bits wouldn't make a lot of sense i.m.o.)

Comment: Do you want a value >= 1 to return 0 or do you want a value 0 to return 1? It's perfectly unclear. Upon reading this I was assuming the former, but someone posted a solution doing the latter.

Comment: Zero to return 1. Any non-zero to return -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting `x` to a boolean does not generate any branches on current x86 processors. You can use simple arithmetics to generate your result:

```
int test_zero(int x) {
    return 1 - 2 * !!x;
}
```

**gcc 11.2** generates this:

```
test_zero:
    cmp     edi, 1
    sbb     eax, eax
    and     eax, 2
    sub     eax, 1
    ret
```

**clang 13.0.0** generates this:

```
test_zero:                              # @test_zero
    xor     eax, eax
    test    edi, edi
    sete    al
    add     eax, eax
    add     eax, -1
    ret
```

As commented by *dratenik*, even simpler and more readable source compiles to exactly the same branchless executable code:

```
int test_zero2(int x) {
    return x ? -1 : 1;
}
```

You check the code generation on [Godbolt's compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/ds31hrM9b).

Comment: You don't even have to do that. gcc -O3 produces very similar cmpl+sbb asembly for the more readable `if (i) { i = -1; } else { i = 1; }`.

Comment: Can't beat those four little instructions. I'll accept this as answer.

Comment: @dratenik, thanks for the tip. It didn't cross my mind to compile with optimizations and see what the compiler makes of my "if".

Answer (score 3):

The clang/gcc output (from the answer by chqrlie) could be truncated a bit to

```
cmp  edi, 1
sbb  eax, eax
or   eax, 1
```

After `sbb eax, eax` we have `eax == 0` for `edi != 0`.
But since -1 and 1 both have the LSB set, we can just make it so.

Alas, even if we can produce a two instruction sequence for

```
int test_zero_3(int x) {
   return x ? -1 : 0;
}
...
neg     edi
sbb     eax, eax
```

we can't fool clang, but we can make gcc to produce the expected (or closely equivalent) sequence

```
int test_zero_4(int x) {
   return (test_zero_3(x)) | 1;
}
...
neg     edi
sbb     eax, eax
or      eax, 1
```

Comment: Thanks, @Aki. I'm on VS actually and I can't fool it either to generate less than four instructions. I won't be able to drop down to writing Asm either. A bit of background on this: I'm writing a processor simulator, and I need the above function for decoding all INC-like and DEC-like instructions; they're encoded identically except for one bit somewhere, which is 0 for INC and 1 for DEC. This is in an innermost loop where a couple instructions make a visible difference overall.

Comment: @adigostin: If you are testing a bit then it is only 0 or 1, not anything else, and that makes it easier: `result = (-bit) | 1`.

Comment: @NateEldredge, yes, it changes the problem I thought I had. I won't be changing the question on this page though. The answers I got here are great and they got me thinking quite a bit. Thanks a lot for the suggestions in these comments.

Comment: @adigostin: Also, if you're extracting a bit from a known position in a word, you can use the shl/sar trick to avoid needing a mask.  `signed int word = ... ; return ((word << pos) >> 31) | 1` generates desired code on MSVC, despite technically being undefined behavior.  This gets you three instructions `shl / sar / or` instead of `shr / and / neg / or` that you would need with a naive shift/mask.

Comment: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/53006